# Get Class Name of Element from MouseEvent Target

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need the class name of an `EventTarget`, which I'm getting like this:

```
<div class="orig-post" (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)"></div>

onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.target = event.target
    console.log(this.target) // Outputs the element the mouse is currently over
}
```

I'd like to be able to assign a variable to the class name of the element that is the target. If I were using something like `getSelection()` I could just do something like `selection.anchorNode.parentElement.className`. Is there a way to do this in pure javascript? I'm using Angular 2 and would like to avoid jQuery entirely.

Comment: `event.target.className`?

Comment: `className` is not a property of `EventTarget`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget

Comment: @J.AdamConnor — That page says "EventTarget is an interface implemented by objects that can receive events and may have listeners for them.

Element, document, and window are the most common event targets" — Element objects most definitely do have a `className` property.

Comment: `(<HTMLElement>event.target).className` or a bit better `(<Element>event.target).className`

Comment: @yurzui Thanks. Put this in answer form and I'll accept. Also, please explain briefly in the solution this use of the Element interface.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In order to silence the typescript warning you can cast `EventTarget` to `Element` and then use `className` property

```
(event.target as Element).className
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="orig-post" (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event.target.value)"></div>

onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.target = event.target
    console.log(this.target) // Outputs the element the mouse is currently over
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
event.target.classList
```